# how to search for referenced document in mongoosejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two Schemas `Organization` and `Location`. On `Organization` Schema i have referenced the Location Schema:

```
Organization = new Schema({
  location: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Location'
  } 
});
```

`Location` schema has fields like country,state, city, district etc.

Now how would I search the `Organization` with specific country or state or city.

What I have found in the Mongoose Document is this way:

```
Organization
.find()
.populate([{path:'location',select:'country state city district' },
 {/*other population paths*/}] /*Some constriants here*/).exec(function(err, orgs){
   console.log(orgs);
});
```

How do I achieve this type of search. Are there any plugins available for this type of reference document search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass match query to select the particular location. Please read the docs [query_populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate).

```
Organization
.find()
.populate([{
   path:'location',
   match : {state : req.query.state} //your query goes here
   select:'country state city district'
}]).exec(function(err, orgs){
  console.log(orgs);
});
```